# Allowing template parameter to be only certain types and deciding action based on it

Tags: c++, templates

Let say i have two classes `MyClass_one` , `MyClass_two`

And i have function that accept only them as first parameter

```
template<typename T,typename ...Ts>
void doSomething(T one, Ts...two){}
```

Now to make it simple, if parameter `one` is `MyClass_one` it should print "im one" if its `MyClass_two` it should print "im two".

How to actually achieve this? The only solution i have came up with is really ugly and does not containt compile error throwing:

```
template<typename T> isOne{ static const bool value = false}
template<> isOne<MyClass_one>{ static const bool value = true}

template<typename T> isTwo{ static const bool value = false}
template<> isTwo<MyClass_two>{ static const bool value = true}

template<typename T, typename ... Ts>
void doSomething(T one, Ts...two){
  if( isOne<T>::value ) { cout << "im one" << endl;}
  else if ( isTwo<T>::value){ cout <<"im two" << endl;}
}
```

However how to implement the compiler error check without overloading (multiple definition of `doSomething()` function) e.g the function will not compile if something else than `MyClass_one` or `MyClass_two` is passed.

thanks for help.

Comment: Template specialization?

Comment: Care to elaborate? Im quite newbie into templates

Comment: You *could* specialize the template for each of the template argument types you care about.

Comment: `isOne` and `isTwo` could be implemented in terms of `std::is_same`, if you want to simplify them.  ...Which in turn means they can also just be replaced with `is_same`.  They could also be combined as a variable template, which could be expanded as necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use C++17, you can use `if constexpr`:

```
template<typename T, typename ... Ts>
void doSomething(T one, Ts...two){
  if constexpr ( isOne<T>::value ) { cout << "im one" << endl;}
  else if constexpr ( isTwo<T>::value){ cout <<"im two" << endl;}
}
```

Of course, `isOne<T>::value` and `isTwo<T>::value` need to be `static constexpr` variables.

If you want to check the types of the first function argument, the same approach holds, only there is no need for something like `isOne` and `isTwo`, you can use `std::is_same_v` to see if the first argument is `MyClassOne` or `MyClassTwo`:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector> 

class MyClassOne {}; 
class MyClassTwo {}; 

template<typename T, typename ... Ts>
void doSomething(T one, Ts...two){
  if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<T, MyClassOne> ) 
    std::cout << "im one" << std::endl;
  else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<T, MyClassTwo> )
    std::cout <<"im two" << std::endl;
  else
    static_assert(false, "Only MyClassOne and MyClassTwo are permitted first arguments.");
}
int                                                                                                                                         
main(int argc, char **argv) { 

    MyClassOne one; 
    MyClassTwo two; 

    doSomething(one, 1.5, two); 
    doSomething(two, 'c', one);

    std::vector<MyClassOne> onesVector;
    doSomething(onesVector, 1.0); 

}
```

`std::is_same_v<A,B>` results in a`true` value if the types `A` and `B` are the same. This answers your question "if parameter one is MyClass_one it should print "im one" if its MyClass_two it should print "im two".", and fails at compile time if the first argument is any type different than etither `myClassOne` or `myClassTwo`.

**Edit**: added a `static_assert` that makes sure the compilation fails if the first argument is anything else except `MyClassOne` or `MyClassTwo`, as suggested by Justin Time in the comment.

Comment: however this would compile even if i passed for example vector as first parameter, my point is that it shouldnt even compile, i will edit question so it wont be confusing

Comment: You can solve that by [adding a `static_assert` to tmaric's code](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/105b7dc0a5877812), @Darlyn.  (Note that the `static_assert` doesn't need to check for both `MyClassOne` and `MyClassTwo`, it only needs to check for one of the types that'd have been caught by one of the previous branches, to guarantee that the result is always `false` without explicitly hard-coding it as `false`.  Checking for either individually, or checking for both, [will have the same result](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eaffebedefc63f8b).)

Answer (score 3):

> without overloading

but overloading here make code simple:

```
template<typename ... Ts>
void doSomething(MyClass_one, Ts...two){
    cout << "im one" << endl;
}

template<typename ... Ts>
void doSomething(MyClass_two, Ts...two){
    cout <<"im two" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest splitting your function in two parts. Keep the iterative part `doSomething` and separate out the actual thing you want done.

```
template<typename T> void theThing(T one);

template<>
void theThing<MyClass_one>(MyClass_one one) {
    cout << "im one" << endl;
}

template<>
void theThing<MyClass_two>(MyClass_two one) {
    cout << "im two" << endl;
}

template<typename T, typename ... Ts>
void doSomething(T one, Ts...two) {
    theThing(one);
}
```

That way, you can have specialized things for every class you want to use. Bonus, it won't compile for types for which `theThing` is not specialized.